# Replace Pandas Dataframe Values with Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a time series dataframe with dates as index and days to maturity "DTM" values. What is the best way to replace these DTM values with actual dates (adding the existing value to the date index row date)?

[image]

For example: Adding 20 days to 1990-01-02 = 1990-01-22 for the first row/first column value.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating similar dataframe to the one you posted:

```
import pandas as pd
array = {'Date': ['1990-01-02', '1990-01-03'],
         'CL1': [20,19],
         'CL2': [49,48], 'CL3': [77,76]}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('Date')
df
```

This gives:

```
           CL1  CL2 CL3
Date            
1990-01-02  20  49  77
1990-01-03  19  48  76
```

Now here is the solution to what you are after:

```
from datetime import timedelta
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(df[col], unit='d') 
df
```

Which gives:

```
                CL1          CL2       CL3
Date            
1990-01-02  1990-01-22  1990-02-20  1990-03-20
1990-01-03  1990-01-22  1990-02-20  1990-03-20
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I trief your code but I get this error: Invalid type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>. Must be int or float.

Comment: Please post here the result of df.dtypes

Comment: CL1     float64
CL2     float64
CL3     float64
CL4     float64
CL5     float64
CL6     float64
CL7     float64
CL8     float64
CL9     float64
CL10    float64
CL11    float64
CL12    float64
dtype: object

Comment: Try the code again. There was a spelling mistake

Comment: Yes, I have already changed that but it still gives me this error. (is the df1 also a typo?)

Comment: df1 was typo. sorry. please run df=df.reset_index() and then post df.dtypes

Comment: Date    datetime64[ns]
CL1            float64
CL2            float64
CL3            float64
CL4            float64
CL5            float64
CL6            float64
CL7            float64
CL8            float64
CL9            float64
CL10           float64
CL11           float64
CL12           float64
dtype: object

Comment: I have posted an amended solution above. Does this work for you?

Comment: Perfect! It works flawlessly. Thank you so much